# In Java, how do I remove the decimal places of an output double when it's an integer but keep them when it's a float?

Tags: java, type-conversion, format, output, double

A user inputs a string numeric value and it can be anything like 3.14 or 10. When converting to a double and printing the value back, I'd like to return integer values like 10 as just "10" and not "10.0" but if the user enters 3.14 I'd still like to return 3.14. I know this could be done using regex and searching the string and then converting the values to an int or double accordingly, but is there an easier way to do this? Here is my simple code:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Systemin);
    System.out.println("Give a number:");
    double value = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.println("You gave the number " + value);
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DecimalFormat for that. # means if the number is present it will display.

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
System.out.println("You gave the number " + format.format(value));
```